# How can I change the OS name from Ubuntu to something else?

Tags: 11.10, system, system-monitor

I want that applications like System Monitor and Conky display the name MYOS instead of Ubuntu 11.10.

Also, I want `lsb_release -a` and etc. to show MYOS only.

Answer (score 9):

You really should not change the content of the `/etc/lsb-release` file.

As you have seen yourself, you will experience problems in applications like Software Center, as these programs need the correct release description. If you simply change this bit of information, the programs are unable to find the proper software repositories, because they are looking for something, which does not exist.

Reedit the file to the old values and Software Center will work again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it my modifying the file lsb-release and issue as per your wish found on the etc dir.

Sample File for lsb-release:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS"
```

Sample File for issue:

```
cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Once you modified reboot the system. You can find the updated content.

Comment: my software center stops starting after doing so

Comment: Mine is located at /etc/os-release not /etc/lsb-release

Answer (score 1):

What Mughil said works and to make the software center work, I would do that in another way.

Sample File for lsb-release:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS"
```

Just change the `DESCRIPTION` but not `ID`, `RELEASE` and `CODENAME`. And also do no modify `/etc/issue` file.