# How do I change the OS Name in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: iso

I am making a distro. I have tried using. Cubic to customize the ISO. I go into settings, and the os name is Ubuntu 20.04, not primeOS. What do I do?

Comment: Does this point you in the right direction: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91297/how-can-i-change-the-os-name-from-ubuntu-to-something-else

Comment: @kgiii yes thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option that comes to my mind, is as follows:

1. Check the content of `lsb-release` file by, `cat /etc/lsb-release`
2. Mine is this

> ```
> DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
> DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
> DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
> DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"
> ```

3. Now with admin rights, edit the `lsb-release` file: `sudo nano /etc/lsb-release` (you may use your preferred editor other than nano)
4. ONLY change the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, to your PrimeOS at `DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"`, save and exit (name must be within " ")
5. Run `lsb_release -a` without root and see if the name changes

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH 